# Why can't you assign an int to an Integer in a loop without curly braces?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why this is not compiling in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974641/why-this-is-not-compiling-in-java)

In java, curly braces are optional for one line for loops, but I've found a case where it isn't allowed. For instance, this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Integer a = i;
```

won't compile, but if you add curly braces, like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Integer a = i;
}
```

it will. Why won't this code compile?

Comment: Interestingly, almost exactly the same question popped a week ago. Was this some interview question? Edit: found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974641/why-this-is-not-compiling-in-java

Comment: That's quite interesting. What version of Java? My guess is it's due to the boxing. But it's a little strange.

Comment: @silky: It's nothing to do with boxing. (In particular it predates boxing by a long way and would happen if `a` was of type `int` too.) It's the difference between a statement-expression and a declaration-statement if memory serves...

Comment: It's *nearly* an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974641/why-this-is-not-compiling-in-java - close enough, IMO.

Comment: Man, that would be a terrible interview question...

Comment: @Jon Skeet & BalusC: It wasn't a interview question, a colleague of mine accidentally ran into it. I didn't find the other question because "Why won't this compile?" is a poor name to try and search against.

Comment: very interesting indeed -- this is the sort of nastiness that C++ is popular for -- it should be something that can be clarified during compile time. I sincerely hope it wasn't a real interview question :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it wouldn't make sense to declare a new variable in a single line statement as it goes out of scope immediately.

If you look at the definition of a [statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.5) in Java, it doesn't include a LocalVariableDeclarationStatement, whereas a [block](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.2) does.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have curly braces, you can't put in a variable declaration.  (The variable would be useless)

See the [specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#6391).  (A *LocalVariableDeclarationStatement* can only occur directly inside of a *Block*.)

Answer (score -2):

I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that the following statement is compound?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Integer a;
    a = i;
```